# Incorrect output for MySQL query run in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MySQL. When I run this query, I get the correct output:

```
select
        m.chirpid as 'Chirp Id',
        c.text as 'Chirp Text',
        c._created as 'Chirp Date'
from mentions m 
join chirps c on c.id = m.chirpid
where m.userid = 1;
```

But when I put the same query in a stored procedure and call it, I get an incorrect output. It returns data for usermentioned = 2 instead of 1. What am I missing? Or how can I debug?

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE spUserMentions
(usermentioned int)
BEGIN
    select
            m.chirpid as 'Chirp Id',
            c.text as 'Chirp Text',
            c._created as 'Chirp Date'
    from mentions m 
    join chirps c on c.id = m.chirpid
    where m.userid = usermentioned;
END//

delimiter ;



call spUserMentions(1);
```

Comment: To debug, I'd start by including usermentioned and m.userid in the output, e.g. `select usermentioned, m.userid, m.chirpid, ...`. Also make sure it really is the wrong output and not e.g. just a different order. And that this is actually the code you are running (e.g. not simplified), and that you are running it on the same database. If you want *us* to debug, you will need to add a reproducible example (as your code doesn't look like it should show this behaviour). Try to create a full example with table create statements and some sample data that shows this behaviour.

Comment: How are using results of the `select` query without using `into` clause in a stored procedure ?

Comment: ok, I feel really dumb. This was just a matter of knowing how to use MySQL's gui. Good debugging advice, @Solarflare, because it led me to realize that I wasn't actually editing the Store Procedure; I needed to use the edit button. duh! I was using the lightning bolt, which is 'run', instead of the wrench, which is 'edit'.